# How to pass -mem to dockerized Play application

Tags: docker, playframework-2.0, sbt-native-packager

I'm using Play! 2.5.  When I run my application, I run it with -mem 4000.  How can I send this option to the Docker image that I create with `activator docker:publish`?  I've looked at the commands specified by `activator show dockerCommands`, and I see the ENTRYPOINT is bin/myappname - can I edit it to add -mem 4000 there?  Or do I need to use -Xmx and -Xms?  Do I put these options somewhere else?  I have seen some references to an application.ini file, but I"m not sure where to put that in a Play! app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poked further around the sbt-native-packager documentation, and under Recipes, found a section on Play.  The less confusing (to me, anyway) way to accomplish this was to add:

```
    javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq(
      // JVM memory tuning
     "-J-Xmx4000m",
     "-J-Xms512m"
    )
```

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended way to add JVM parameters to your application

Answer (score 1):

In a plain Dockerfile with an `ENTRYPOINT`, you can use `CMD` to specify the options passed to the entry point command.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/myappname"]
CMD [ "-mem", "4000" ]
```

Sorry I'm not a scala person and don't know how to apply this to the sbt/activator/play generator, although [the `dockerCommands` section here](https://conductr.lightbend.com/docs/1.1.x/CreatingBundles#Docker-bundles) seems relevant, also [this Codacy blog post](https://blog.codacy.com/dockerizing-scala-afbe9e55aaea).

> Let’s override the dockerComands in our build.sbt by adding:
>
> ```
> dockerCommands := dockerCommands.value.flatMap{
>   case cmd@Cmd(“FROM”,_) => List(cmd, Cmd(“RUN”, “apk update && apk add bash”))
>   case other => List(other) }
> }
> ```

So possibly

```
dockerCommands := dockerCommands.value.flatMap{
  case cmd@ExecCmd("ENTRYPOINT",_) => List(cmd, ExecCmd("CMD", """[ "-mem", "4000" ]"""))
  case other => List(other) }
}
```